# Invoice2Data template not found

Tags: python-3.x, templates, invoice

I am currently trying to parse some invoice data and came across this package on PyPi. It seems to be very handy for this task. There is one problem I can't run it due to 'no template found for ' error. From the documentation [https://pypi.org/project/invoice2data/0.2.31/#description]

it becomes clear that you need to specify a template and then run the following command: `invoice2data <invoice_file>.pdf`. To specify a template you need to run the command `invoice2data --template-folder <yourfolder>`.

When executing these commands in my wsl (Linux virtual machine, needed to run package) it keeps complaining. My invoice files are in the map 'tpl' (2 custom yml files), and the invoice file is called invoice.pdf see screenshots. I have attached the invoices too for clearity, please not these are all testfiles. My aim is to first make sure invoice2data operates, and then make my own custom YML template conforming the tutorial.

Somehow invoice2data does not get, it needs to assign a template ( I really don't care about which template at this stage) to execute the parsing. I have looked everywhere on google, there are topics on these, but none offer me a solution. I hope somebody can help me out. Much appreciated, tnx a lot in advance

Jeffrey

[1. files and directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQDZ0.jpg)

[2. YML template files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdv9S.jpg)

[3. Command line execution gives error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XdJG.jpg)

[4a. invoice sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh2AP.jpg)

[4b. invoice sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jytO2.jpg)

Comment: HI! Were you able to solve this issue? I am facing it at the moment and have no idea why

Comment: Hi, i've used all the path ('/home/user/Documents/project/templates') and just works.